# Do you have to completely master each Pumping Nylon exercises thoroughly?

Tags: practice, tempo, classical-guitar, exercises

Presently I am working on Pumping Nylon exercises, but I cannot play as fast as the exercise asks me to.

Do I have to completely master each piece or can I just move on after playing through it moderately fine?

Comment: I think this question applies to many technique training books and video tutorials. I'd go as far as to say, _most_ students initially face the same problem. What does this book itself say?

Answer (score 3):

Is the course guaranteeing that once completed perfectly you'll become a concert guitarist? I doubt it!

So, use each exercise as just that. An exercise. Do it to the best of your ability, move on to another. It may well be that after a period of time - a couple of weeks - several years - that you'll be capable of playing it at the recommended tempo. But until then, there are many other fish to fry. Speed is only one consideration when playing. Probably not the most important.

Learning to get a better tone, playing with more feeling, understanding what you're actually doing, come higher up my list. The tempi suggested are ideas (ideals?) from the author, and thus are subjective, not necessarily objective. As long as you can play each without error, at *your* maximum speed, that's sufficient. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Unless the book itself tells you it's necessary, then no. Take each exercise as far as you can, but then return to them periodically. Tempos are an ideal given by the author, but any guitarist might max out at a slower or higher tempo. But in general, exercises that you played at a certain top speed earlier, will become faster as you grow overall.

Returning periodically to any material is a good idea in music generally, with the understanding that "periodically" could mean months or even years. I once knew a pianist who at 98 was still studying pieces he learned at 20, and he was still finding new things in them.